# Restriction of a very ample line bundle on complete intersection curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth complete intersection curve in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$, $f$ be a linear polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[X_0,...,X_3]$ which does not vanish identically on $C$. Denote by $U$ the open affine set in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined by the non-vanishing of $f$. Is it true that for any positive integer $a$, the natural restriction morphism $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(a)) \to H^0(U,\mathcal{O}_C(a)|_U)$ is surjective?

There seems to be some confusion.  I want to stress on the fact that I do not take any open set and any curve. I elaborate here the motivation and some more details. As far as I understand $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(a))$ is the degree $a$ graded  part of $\mathbb{C}[X_0,...,X_3]/I_C$ when $C$ is a complete intersection curve. Assume that $f=X_0$.The question is, whether $\mathcal{O}_C(a)(U \cap C)$ is the degree $a$ graded part of $\mathbb{C}[X_1',...,X_3']/I_C$, where $X_i':=X_i/X_0$. It seems to me from the definition that this should be the case. If so, then the natural morphism sending $X_0$ to $1$ and $X_i$ to $X_i'$ should give us the surjective morphism mentioned in the original question. Is this a bit more clear? Is this wrong?

Can someone please verify this argument.

Comment: Is $U$ supposed to be an open set in $\mathbf P^3$, or in the curve $C$? You said the first one, but then the "restriction morphism" you are asking about does not make sense...

Comment: Anyway, assuming you are restricting to an open set in the curve, then this map will not be surjective in general. E.g. suppose $C$ is a line $\mathbf P^1$ in $\mathbf P^3$: do we ever get a surjection of global sections when we restrict a line bundle to an open set?

Comment: OK, after the edit it now makes sense: you had a $U$ before where you should have had $U \cap C$. My second comment still answers the question, though: if $C$ is a linearly embedded copy of $\mathbf P^1$ then $O_C(a)(U \cap C)$ is infinite-dimensional, because $U \cap C$ is just $\mathbf P^1 - \{pt\} = \mathbf A^1$ so any line bundle on it is trivial.

Comment: @Dubh: I am sorry, I am a bit confused. Why is $\mathcal{O}_C(a)(U \cap C)$ is infinite-dimensional? If I understand correctly, it should be generated by $(X_1/X_0)^a$ or $(X_0/X_1)^a$ depending on $U$. Hence, just one dimensional. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. There is no reason that a section in $\mathcal{O}_C(a)(U \cap C)$ needs to be of that form. As I said before, $U \cap C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf A^1$, so $O_C(a)$ restricted to that set is the trivial bundle.

Comment: Dubh: Thanks, I think I understand.